# Create table form doctrine orm.xml file

Tags: xml, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony4

I am using some project with doctrine (for the first time) without annotations.

Doctrine mappings are set in xxx.orm.xml files.
There are multiple namespaces in the project.

Problem is that command

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

are not setting any new table in the database.

What I do wrong ion this case, how to register new files for doctrine mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding new namespace,

**`doctrine.yaml`**

should be updated

i.e.

```
App\Entity:
                type: xml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Doctrine/Mapping/Domain'
                is_bundle: false
                prefix: App\Entity
                alias: Entity
```